# Time complexity of computing $AA^T$

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, matrices

What is the time complexity of computing $AA^T$? The context is building a co-citation weighted adjacency matrix.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried to work out the time complexity of computing $A^T$ and of the matrix multiplication?  What research have you done?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.  What properties does $A$ have?  Is it dense, or sparse, or what?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4107537/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139101/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You also need to be a bit more specific about the matrix. Operations on sparse matrices tend to have different algorithms to operations on dense matrices, for example.

Comment: The time complexity depends on the algorithm. Which algorithm do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $n \times m$ dense matrix then $AA^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrices given by
$$
(AA^T)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ik} A_{jk}.
$$
This gives a $\Theta(n^2m)$ algorithm for computing $AA^T$.

If $n \geq m$ then faster algorithms exist, but they are not used in practice (at least in most situations).

If $A$ is sparse, that is, stored as a list of non-zero entries, then $AA^T$ can be calculated using different algorithms which exploit the sparsity of $A$. For example, we can sort the non-zero entries in $A$ according to the second coordinate, and then compute $AA^T$ by going over all $k$ and adding $A_{ik} A_{jk}$ to $(AA^T)_{ij}$ for any $i,j$ in the list of $k$. If $s$ is the sparsity of $A$ and $s_k$ is the number of non-zero entries with second coordinate equal to $k$, then this runs in time
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m \binom{s_k+1}{2} \propto \sum_{k=1}^m s_k^2 \in [s^2/m,s^2].
$$
Therefore the worst-case running time is $\Theta(s^2)$, and the best-case running time is $\Theta(s^2/m)$.

Comment: Also, asymptotically, $AA^T$ is no easier to compute than general matrix multiplication $BC$: putting $A=\Bigl(\frac{B}{C^T}\Bigr)$, one can read $BC$ off of $AA^T=\Bigl(\frac{BB^T|BC}{C^TB^T|C^TC}\Bigr)$.